# ROS3D.Viewer not appearing

Tags: ros, ros3djs, robotwebtools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With [our custom package](https://github.com/tork-a/visualization_rwt/tree/hydro-devel/rwt_moveit), I used to be able to show `ROS3D.Viewer` object on `Chrome` last year but now I can't. So what can cause `ROS3D.Viewer` to not appear in general?
Sorry for sounding elementary; I'm still new to web app dev and I can't even think of what info I should provide, without advices from experts.

Live demos on http://robotwebtools.org/demos.html seem to be working for me, so my environment should be configured fine for RWT to work properly.

Environment:

- Ubuntu 12.04. FF32.0, Chromium 37.0.2062.94
- OSX 10.9.5  37.0.2062.122

---

If someone wants to run, [there's a readme](https://github.com/tork-a/visualization_rwt/blob/hydro-devel/rwt_moveit/README.rst) but the package is still under development and the way it installs is hacky for now.

It used to look like this:
[image description http://wiki.ros.org/rtmros_nextage?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=nxo_rwt_moveit_1.png](http://wiki.ros.org/rtmros_nextage?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=nxo_rwt_moveit_1.png)

Now. `ROS3D.Viewer` pane is not shown:
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193334/ros3d.viewer-not-appearing/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2014-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We got it working by simply changing the way to specify the size of `ROS3D.Viewer` object ([commit](https://github.com/tork-a/visualization_rwt/commit/1bc5421fc7edbefc23ad15d0788f14a03b1b25a2)).

%1 Still, I'm not yet sure how it used to work and now doesn't, wondering if [this issue](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs/issues/108) I just opened in `roslibjs` is related or not.

%2 ref. I also opened a [ticket](https://github.com/tork-a/visualization_rwt/issues/38) in a dev repository, and opened a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robot-web-tools/hnV_gt-lhQU/4VM2TLMcZb0J) in rwt forum.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0